# Two Independently TRUE SQL Statements Are Combining to a FALSE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using Transact SQL and am having an issue with the following sample code evaluating to true:

```
CASE
  WHEN [ProductName] = 'Example' AND [Payment] > 0 THEN 'Category A'
  ELSE 'Category B'
END
```

Is this issue somehow caused by a type error? When checked independently, they each resolve to 'Category A'. However, when joined with the AND statement, they resolve to 'Category B'.

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  But your subscription suggests that the two values never meet both conditions in the same row.

Comment: Your question is lacking critical details. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: Agree with the above comments. But something else to consider: "computers never do what I want, but they always do what I tell them to do". I'll bet that the computer is doing exactly what you have asked it to do, and doing it correctly; and that the title of this question is mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you are checking may evaluate to `'Category A'` when you run them independently. However, this doesn't mean that your code will evaluate to `'Category A'` when you run them with AND logical operator.

It looks like you don't have a row in the your table/view that meets both conditions (`[ProductName] = 'Example' AND [Payment] > 0`) in the same row.

Have you checked your condition with the following query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE [ProductName] = 'Example' AND [Payment] > 0
```